# Can some one help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Tags: c++

I was working on a problem from leet code and the question was:

> You are a product manager and currently leading a team to develop a new product. Unfortunately, the latest version of your product fails the quality check. Since each version is developed based on the previous version, all the versions after a bad version are also bad.
>   Suppose you have n versions [1, 2, ..., n] and you want to find out the first bad one, which causes all the following ones to be bad.
>   You are given an API `bool isBadVersion(version)` which will return whether version is bad. Implement a function to find the first bad version. You should minimize the number of calls to the API.

The solutions I had for the problem above was:

```
// Forward declaration of isBadVersion API.
bool isBadVersion(int version);

class Solution 
{
    public:
        int firstBadVersion(int n) 
        {
            bool x = isBadVersion(n);
            if (x == true) 
            {
                return n;
            }
            else
            {
                return firstBadVersion(n + 1);
            }
        }
};
```

But on leet code it says I have the wrong solution.
Could someone please point me in the right direction...

The explanation I got from leet code was:

> Input: 2 versions
>             1 is the first bad version.
>   Output: 2
>   Expected: 1

Comment: Golden section or binary search would be one way to minimize the number of calls...  it seems to me that this is a bigger part of the problem than simply getting an answer.  Running through the list one-by-one is not really a very inventive strategy...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search

Comment: You should have tested this yourself, before submitting it to the robot.

Comment: thanks for the downvote who ever it was.. maybe i should jst quit asking questions here!!  oh well.

Comment: By the way, since the problem was really in a part of the code you didn't show us, you should in the future post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will actually find the first bad version, *on or after* the version passed in (`n`). In other words, it depends on what you pass in.

I *suspect* that what's actually passed in is the highest version (though the specs aren't clear on this, it makes sense), meaning you'll always give the highest version rather than the lowest one. You would be better off with something like (pseudo-code):

```
def findfirstbad(n):
    for i = 1 to n:
        if isbadversion(i):
            return i
    return sentinel # 0 or -1 or some other NA response.
```

In any case, minimising the API calls will need the use of a binary search algorithm, which you should investigate. What you currently have is a recursive *linear* search which will not minimise the number of calls.

Whereas a linear search removes one possible item on each iteration (or recursion), a binary search will remove half the remaining space each time. The pseudo-code for that would go something like:

```
def findfirstbad(n):
    # No bad version possible if no versions.

    if n < 1:
        return sentinel

    # Start pincer at ends.

    lastgood = 0
    firstbad = n

    # Continue until lastgood and firstbad are together.

    while lastgood + 1 < firstbad:
        # Find midpoint, adjust correct pincer.

        mid = (lastgood + firstbad) / 2
        if isbadversion(mid):
            firstbad = mid
        else:
            lastgood = mid

    # Ensure one last check in case there were no bad versions.

    if isbadversion(firstbad):
        return firstbad
    return sentinel
```

If you run that code in your head with the assistance of pen and paper, you'll see that it gradually brings in the `lastgood/firstbad` indexes until it locates the first bad one (or discovers there *is* no bad one).

Then a simple check will decide whether you've found it or not, and return the version if you have found it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I realize what was happening now.

Answer (score 3):

You’re starting from the last version and counting *up*.

Comment: how is he starting from the last version?

Comment: `You should minimize the number of calls to the API.`.. Maybe that's why his answer is wrong.

Comment: That would make the answer slow, not incorrect.  We don’t have a compilable example to see how this was called, but the initial value must have been 2.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't realize I was starting from the last version there.. fixed it now. although i realize this is probably really bad way to solve this problem , but I really wanted to find out why I was getting the wrong answer every time!